# Python - Download a file from aspx form

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm trying to get automaticly some data from this site : 
http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/en/Negociation-History.aspx?Cat=24&IdLink=225

using urllib2 in python, I got successfully an html file as if I click on "submit" button in this web site.

But, when I simulate the behaviour of clicking in the link "download data" I got anything as output.

My code is :

```
import urllib
import urllib2

uri = 'http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/en/Negociation-History.aspx?Cat=24&IdLink=225'
headers = {
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
}

formFields = (
    (r'TopControl1$ScriptManager1', r'HistoriqueNegociation1$UpdatePanel1|HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$LinkButton1'),
    (r'__EVENTTARGET', r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$LinkButton1'),
    (r'__EVENTARGUMENT', r''),
    (r'__VIEWSTATE', r'/wEPDwUKMTcy/ ... +ZHYQBq1hB/BZ2BJyHdLM='), #just a small part because it's so long !
    (r'TopControl1$TxtRecherche', r''),
    (r'TopControl1$txtValeur', r''),
    (r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DDValeur', r'9000  '),
    (r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$historique', r'RBSearchDate'),
    (r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DateTimeControl1$TBCalendar', r'22/12/2014'),
    (r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DateTimeControl2$TBCalendar', r'28/12/2014'),
    (r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DDuree', r'6'),
    (r'hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts', r'1')
)


encodedFields = urllib.urlencode(formFields)

req = urllib2.Request(uri, encodedFields, headers)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

What should I do in order to get the same file as if I click on the "download data" link in the site ?

Thank you

Comment: Cause the `ASP.NET` form-specific values change every time you retrieve a page, you need to parse the values from the HTML you get, not hardcode them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you to usу [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library instead urllib. Also we need a [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for working with HTML tags:

```
pip install requests

pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Than, code will look like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

payload = {
    r'TopControl1$ScriptManager1': r'HistoriqueNegociation1$UpdatePanel1|HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$LinkButton1',
    r'__EVENTTARGET': r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$LinkButton1',
    r'__EVENTARGUMENT': r'',
    r'TopControl1$TxtRecherche': r'',
    r'TopControl1$txtValeur': r'',
    r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DDValeur': r'9000  ',
    r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$historique': r'RBSearchDate',
    r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DateTimeControl1$TBCalendar': r'22/12/2014',
    r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DateTimeControl2$TBCalendar': r'28/12/2014',
    r'HistoriqueNegociation1$HistValeur1$DDuree': r'6',
    r'hiddenInputToUpdateATBuffer_CommonToolkitScripts': r'1'
  }


uri = 'http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/en/Negociation-History.aspx?Cat=24&IdLink=225'
r = session.get(uri)

#Find __VIEWSTATE value, there is only one input tag with type="hidden"
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
viewstate_tag = soup.find('input', attrs={"type" : "hidden"})
payload[viewstate_tag['name']] = viewstate_tag['value']

r = session.post(uri, payload)
print r.text #contains html table with data
```

First, we get the original page, extract `__VIEWSTATE` value and use that value for the second request.