# How to scrape an aspx file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to collect data from this aspx file (French website):
https://www.statsf1.com/fr/2021/emilie-romagne/tour-par-tour.aspx

For each lap, I'd like to know wether the safety car was deployed, that means, according to the HTML code that for each `<tr class="lap">` if there is `<td title="Safety Car" class="numlap sc">1</td>` and if so to collect the lap number in a list.

Here is the code I've tried but the `laps_` variable is still empty

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_data=requests.get('https://www.statsf1.com/fr/2021/emilie-romagne/tour-par-tour.aspx')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_data.content)
laps_=soup.find_all('td',title_='Safety Car')
```

PS: I've tried looking at [Python - Download a file from aspx form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697487/python-download-a-file-from-aspx-form) but I haven't been able to do any better

Comment: The aspx doesn't matter - it just means the page was generated by .net - its just HTML that you are looking at.

Comment: _"it didn't work"_ is not a problem description.

Comment: The issue I have is that `html_data.content` and `html_data.text` are empty even after the `request.get('URL')` and so is the `soup` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `user-agent` to request headers and then you'll get the `HTML`. Also, you can use `pandas` to parse the tables.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://www.statsf1.com/fr/2021/emilie-romagne/tour-par-tour.aspx"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
}

tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, flavor="bs4")
print(tables[0].head(10))
```

Output:

```
  Unnamed: 0 HAM1 PER2 VER3 LEC4 GAS5  ... ALO15 RAI16 GIO17 MSC18 MAZ19 TSU20
0          1  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   TSU   MSC   ALO   VET   MAZ   NaN
1          2  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   MSC   ALO   VET   MAZ   OCO   NaN
2          3  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   MSC   ALO   MAZ   OCO   VET   NaN
3          4  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   ALO   MAZ   OCO   VET   MSC   NaN
4          5  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   ALO   MAZ   OCO   VET   MSC   NaN
5          6  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   ALO   MAZ   OCO   VET   MSC   NaN
6          7  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   ALO   OCO   VET   MAZ   MSC   NaN
7          8  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   ALO   OCO   VET   MAZ   MSC   NaN
8          9  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   ALO   OCO   VET   MAZ   MSC   NaN
9         10  VER  HAM  LEC  PER  RIC  ...   OCO   VET   ALO   MAZ   MSC   NaN
```